# Setting up a Database in-house for whole company use

Tags: database, postgresql, network-drive

I started exploring Databases and PostgreSQL not long ago, my goal is to create a database for my company, in which I can upload data and other people can access it through ODBC connections and explore it in Excel. I managed to create a test database in my PC and everything worked properly.
I then moved to the next step, which would be sharing this test database with my colleagues.

I guess that the database could not be stored in my own PC (as it is today) , because people need to be able to access it even when it is turned off.

We have a Network Drive, where currently all our data is stored. **Is it possible to host my database in there? What else should I know for this project I'm conducting?**

I'm quite new to the subject and I'm just trying to explore some possibilities.

(We all run Windows)

Comment: This question would suit better ServerFault forum. But no, network drive isn't enough. You need a database server. Shared disk isn't enough. But there are lot of cloud databases you could use. Easier and cheaper than maintenance your own server. Just google "hosted postgresql".

Comment: About hosted postgres server. Postgres has published list of providers. That would probably be even better place to start searching your service provider than plain google search: https://www.postgresql.org/support/professional_hosting/

Comment: Thank you for both comments! I'll start my search by the link you sent.